# Eclipse - My app has collapsed - MainActivity and AndroidManifest are blank

Tags: eclipse

I'm about to lose my mind.

Yesterday I was working a bit to get some ads in my app, which I'm trying for a long time, since there is -no- good tutorial that clears out easily on how to put them.

Anyway, yesterday I wanted to close my pc, and I got  blue screen, for those who know, it's announcing a crash of your pc.

I shut down the pc manually, and at the restart, I cleaned the pc (dutch: "schrijfdefragmentatie') twice.

After that, I wanted to open Eclipse, and I got many, many errors, about Parser exception for /MainActivity/AndroidManifest.xml: Premature end of file.

and that about all my apps.

I'm trying to open AndroidManifest.xml, which gave a red error-icon, but now it's totally blank!

As for my src\com.example.appname\MainActivity.java, it's also blank !

I fear that I've lost my app due to this.

Though, I got my app on my cellphone (Android).

Can I get that version back on my pc? Because this has the only relevant code and stuff.
Or is there another way to save my app?

Comment: Right click on the Project and select 'Restore from Local History...' to see if Eclipse has any backups.

Comment: That is clearly an indication that you should be using some source code management system, like GIT for instance

Comment: I found another backup of my file, but it gives a particular error:
[2014-08-13 14:42:47 - Timer] Parser exception for /Timer/AndroidManifest.xml: Premature end of file.

Comment: == FIXED !! ==  Ty all !                                              ( I just restarted the script, which gave me a new AndroidManifest.xml, and it did the trick!